# Programatically update posts in database from one block to another using transform

Tags: javascript, block-editor

**Scenario:**
I've made a plugin which is similar to or compatible with another solution.

On activation of this new plugin, I'd like to start migration of all the existing content in the pages over to the new solution.

**Problem**
Now initially I thought I could leverage the functions in the `wp` object and my new block using the `switchToBlockType`[*no docs link but accessible via* `wp.blocks.switchToBlockType()`] and either [`replaceBlocks`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-editor/#replaceblocks) or something manual on an admin options page with some Ajax calls and processing functions. I've altered the filter for my options page to load the block editor scripts and styles.

[`add_filter( 'should_load_block_editor_scripts_and_styles', '__return_true' );`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/should_load_block_editor_scripts_and_styles/)

I cannot however get any core blocks to parse, and I'm not sure why. All the non-core blocks are parsed into Block Objects OK.

**I've tried**

- I have tried listing EVERY SINGLE script [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/contributors/code/scripts/) as a dependency of
  the file but no core blocks are converted from a sample payload of
  block editor HTML. The same code does parse it ok on the post.php edit
  pages.
- I've tried running the code globally from the console after all scripts are 100% loaded.
- Looking through the sources and comparing - making sure the [`registerBlockType`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-registration/#registerblocktype) functions have been included for the core blocks in `/wp-includes/js/dist/block-library.js`

I feel like this must be possible, but I'm missing a bit of core knowledge that someone out there will have - I'd rather do it this way than string replacement and converting in PHP.

---

**Edit for clarity**

This is the code below I am using to parse the `post_content` payload where the var `contentGbHtml` is a sample of post content taken from the DB. [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/2BqtTsyU)

```js
    var pageBlocks = wp.blocks.rawHandler({
        HTML: contentGbHtml
    });

    //do something with pageBlocks -? (switchToBlockType / createBlock & block migrations with innerBlocks from object 

    return wp.blocks.serialize( pageBlocks );
```

The return would then be saved in the database as new post content with your block edits made. Inspiration for this was taken from [Bulk Block Converter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-block-converter/) - I can't find the original repo - [this is a forked copy](https://github.com/ZamanehMedia/vo-bulk-block-converter/blob/master/js/scripts.js#L167) at the line where this is handled on the admin front-end

The code works fine with the same payload on the `post.php` page. On my options page with the above filter set. Only 3rd party blocks are rendered. Any others - such as columns,  paragraphs and headers are simply missed from the returned array of block objects. This is missed from both top level blocks or nested innerBlocks.

[Here is a diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/C5BxLMWI) of the two returned values from the `rawHandler` the 1st from the post.php page the 2nd from my options page.

Comment: When you say _"I cannot however get any core blocks to parse and I'm not sure why."_ can you be more specific? It's unclear/ambiguous, anything you can add code wise too would be helpful

Comment: HI @TomJNowell - thanks for your response. So what I mean is when using a post_content payload containing core blocks none are returned as rendered block objects. I have updated with some test code I have been using and an example of the output

Comment: of course they aren't, unless those blocks are loaded there is nothing to generate a save component. On top of that, some blocks are rendered on the server at runtime. As an aside, why are you converting every block on plugin activation? This is a risky thing to do, and a very unexpected thing to happen when activating a plugin. What happens if there are more posts than your plugin can process during activation and it only gets half way? Also judging from your diff are you sure that the problem is that core blocks are not rendering?

Comment: the first example of missing blocks in your diff does not show that they aren't rendering, it shows that the gutenslider is missing inner blocks. I believe this is purely a coincidence that your innerblocks only contained core blocks which lead to a misunderstanding of the problem. I don't believe it's possible to answer this without seeing the full code of what you're trying to fix as well as the context for why you're doing it. This is a very strange thing to do and it's incredibly difficult to debug code you can't see

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell - there are plenty of core blocks in the main content and in the gutenslider - [pastebin of payload here](https://pastebin.com/2BqtTsyU) I'll make a codepen or something to show the intended use. Sidenote: whilst I agree it's an unusual thing to do I hope it's not _strange_. I'd like to see more solutions in the future that can allow users to migrate their content between plugins - competition breeds creativity - and how many people are stuck on the same rubbish solution because it's too much effort to move?! *puts hand up*

Comment: I've also updated the question with more information whilst I get a codepen ready

Comment: **that's what block transforms are for**, alowing the user to transform one block type into another in the editor, but you wouldn't auto-migrate on plugin activation as that could destroy data, and if it goes wrong the consequences are disastrous. At the very least I would expect such a feature to have a button I can click to trigger it. You run the risk that your plugin won't activate because of the PHP error when it reaches the time execution limit. If I installed a plugin to test out that did what you're trying to do I'd be super peeved and uninstall it for messing up my site

Comment: It's also a given a plugin that does this would never pass the .org plugin repository checks. This is the canonical solution to the problem you're tackling: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-transforms/. What you're doing is inherently risky with no guarantee that once it starts working it will keep working

Comment: Thanks Tom - I have a working Transform and this one wouldn't be for the .org repo. This one's 'client knows best' and wants it done in batch...